# why we cannot use "innerHTML" function directly in loop instead of concatenating the text in order to get a vertical written list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, innerhtml

why we cannot use "innerHTML"  function directly in loop instead of concatenating the text in order to get a vertical written list?

```js
const pk = document.getElementById('pk');

function validation(){
    var word = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var arr = word.split(" ");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
        let boko = document.createElement('div');
        boko.setAttribute('id', 'boko');
        pk.appendChild(boko);
        document.getElementById("boko").innerHTML = i;
    }
}
```

here i am not getting output as 0 1 2 3 instead i am getting only 3...
i replaced `" text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";"` this statement.. but it seems that its not working please help me solve the issue.

Comment: You are creating multiple elements with the id "boko" thats why it does not work. you can delete the `boko.setAttribute('id', 'boko');` and replace `document.getElementById("boko").innerHTML = i;` with `boko.innerHTML = i;` (you already have the div element in the boko variable, you don't need to get it with `document.getElementById` again)

Comment: i want my output to be displayed like in vertical section each number in different div, i am getting the desired answer in console.log properly but here instead of that i am getting only final output that too in single div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a reference to your `div`, so you don't need to assign it an `id` -- you can just set its `innerHTML` directly.

```js
const pk = document.getElementById('pk');

function validation() {
    var word = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var arr = word.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let boko = document.createElement('div');
        boko.innerHTML = i;
        pk.appendChild(boko);
    }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for `createElement(...)` -- it returns a `HTMLElement` which you can modify directly (at least in the case of `createElement('div')`)